# AuthenticationMechanism return payload for 401 with JSON not HTML

Tags: java, security, authentication, enterprise

I've implemented the `HttpAuthenticationMechanism` where in case the user is not authenticated we would like to return a 401 status HTTP response **with a JSON payload**. Currently we return `context.responseUnauthorized` which returns the correct status of the HTTP response as 401 but the payload is in HTML format Unauthorized.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the header of the response with following line:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Tried it already. `context.getResponse().setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");` and `context.getResponse().setContentType("application/json");`, neither worked... The response is still `Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8` for `return context.responseUnauthorized();` where context is of type `HttpMessageContext`